# Subtotals in VBA

Tags: vba

[image][image][image]I have the following code in VBA, it is creating a pivot table and it brings the subtotals for the columns by using pvf.Subtotals(2) = True.
Actually it gives the SUM for all columns but I want to have the average for the last column (Sls %) instead of the SUM.

I tried using Set pvf = gWO.AddDataField(pvt, papercostp, xlAverage) But it gives some values in minus as you can see in the last column.
I have posted the original data and the pivot table.

Can you please advise on how to get SUM for some columns and average for some other columns?

Here is the code:

```
    Set pvf = gWO.AddRowField(pvt, bdnaam)
    
    pvf.Subtotals(2) = True

    Set pvf = gWO.AddRowField(pvt, aorder)
    Set pvf = gWO.AddRowField(pvt, ordnam)
    Set pvf = gWO.AddDataField(pvt, salesamount)
    Set pvf = gWO.AddDataField(pvt, papercost)
    Set pvf = gWO.AddDataField(pvt, papercostp, xlAverage)
```

Comment: Might help to explain a little bit for example what is `gWO`.  It's better if we don't need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

The default function for AddDataField is "Sum" or xlSum. You need to use xlAverage on the columns you want the average. E.g. `Set pvf= gWO.AddDataField(pvt, papercostp, xlAverage)`

Here is the reference material [PivotTable.AddDataField method, Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.adddatafield)

Comment: Hi @CHill60, thanks for your kind reply, I have used the average for the specific column but it has given a strange number which is -41306 in all rows, here is the output before and after 
before:
  Sales Cost cost% 
  13077 3884 30 
  10190 5866 58 
Subtotal 23267 9750 88 
After:
  Sales Cost cost% 
  13077 3884 -41306 
  10190 5866 -41586 
Subtotal 23267 9750 -41586   
For last column (%) I want the average which will be more accurate
If you see in above example, first line % is 30 and 2nd line % is 58, subtotal is 88, I want the average for the 2 lines instead of the total.

Comment: Try updating your post with some actual data examples. The average works fine for me with my data, so it must be something to do with your specific data scenario

Comment: Hi @CHill60 the figures that i have given in my previous note are actual figures: 23267 9750 -41586 (the first 2 values 23267 9750 are for another 2 columns and they are accurate, the last value -41586 is the value i got under the field papercostp after i have used Set pvf= gWO.AddDataField(pvt, papercostp, xlAverage)

Comment: Please note that i'm using pvf.Subtotals(2) = True for grouping the data by customer name and for getting the subtotal for each customer, do i need to change something here?

Comment: The figures you provided are the results of the pivot - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @CHill60 I got your point, Here is the actual data (pls let me know if possible to attach the output of excel): please note I just copied the pivotTable output of that specific field at the last column: CUSTOMER NAME              . Order Sales Amount Paper Cost Paper cost % Paper cost % 
ABC 1390339 38166 13798 36 -41366
ABC 1390361 36062 19979 55 -41556
ABC 1390395 38442 18978 49 -41496
ABC 1390883 32543 11212 34 -41346
ABC 1391160 32039 16015 50 -41506
ABC 1391813 34056 11485 34 -41346
ABC 1391814 70695 39710 56 -41566
     -413146

Comment: And here is the actual output figures of only Average column: Paper cost %
36
55
49
34
50
34
56
And here is the output of same column from Pivot table: Paper cost % 
-41366
-41556
-41496
-41346
-41506
-41346
-41566
-413146

Comment: Hi @CHill60 Actually i have noticed that the figures in minus is still correct but it is in a wrong format, when i click on the cell it displays the right value in Formula bar, however it is still giving Sum against the subtotal instead of Average, any advise please?

Comment: Can someone assist, please? is there a solution to get Subtotals as Average for some columns and as Sum for some other columns through VBA?

Comment: I've shown you how to do that. I can't work out why it is not working for you because you don't share your data in a readable format. Update your post with the table of data you are trying to pivot and also update the code to what you are now using

Comment: Thanks Chill for your reply again, I tried to update the post with excel data but after i save the post, the data format is getting changed, I can share my desk to have a quick look if it is okay with you, kindly let me know.

Comment: Hello Chill @Chill I have edited the original post and have added the original data from the 'Data Tab' and the pivot table as well, kindly have a look. Note: I just manually changed the customer name and the order name just for privacy.